# How to connect to a KDB Database through a Unix script?

Tags: sql, bash, shell, unix, kdb

There are many examples to connect to a Sybase db via unix script. Whats the syntax for connecting to a KDB database?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a KDB database? The tag wiki is empty. A Google search produces [this](http://kx.com/kdb+.php)... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, kdb+. Its a high performance database.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke a Q script to connect to the kdb database from your Unix script.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if a shell based client is available.